# How to makes image resource works nicely for both Iphone3 and Iphone4

Tags: iphone, resolution, iphone-4

I have an application that the UI Image resources are designed target iphone3 screen (320*480), which looks not perfect on iphone4,  is there any way to make it also looks nice on iphone4 ? what I'm thinking is have two different set of resources for different resolution and choose it at runtime according ios version.  Is there any better way ?

Answer (score 3):

See *Updating Your Image Resource Files* in [*Drawing and Printing Guide for iOS: Supporting High-Resolution Screens In Views*](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/2ddrawing/conceptual/drawingprintingios/SupportingHiResScreensInViews/SupportingHiResScreensInViews.html).

Comment: The document linked to is now out of date, and redirects somewhere else.

Comment: This is why a) I provided the titles, so the documentation could be easily found when it moved, and b) Stack Overflow users with over 2000 reputation can suggest helpful edits to other people's answers.